# PHP Progress Update While Executing

Tags: php

Is there a way to get PHP to show you progress while the page is executing a large script? For example if I'm parsing a large array can I output a status update throughout the process?

Comment: And what did you find thus far?

Comment: the page is white the entire time the script is parsing the array

Comment: I would just show a spinning wheel

Comment: Yes, but it is a bit complicated. You'd essentially have to create "checkpoints" in your working (large) script and then create a status-reporting script that reports how many of those checkpoints you've completed. Then poll the status-reporting script via JS and update the page. Look how this is done here: http://chemicaloliver.net/programming/php-5-4-file-upload-progress-and-html5-progress-bars/

Comment: It seems that may work, anyone out there done this with something other than uploading files?

Comment: Thus far I ended up writing a status update to the database each time the script process a large batch within the array..Then I just query the database with ajax and php to get a status update :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four ways to do this I can think of. I've only ever used two of them:

1) You can push output (flush) periodically and HOPE it get's through to the browser. This is likely to work only in certain curcumstances - the web server (apache) will probably have it's own caching and hold up the data for you until it has a large enough amount, the ISP / Workplace / User may have their own caching that may not forward the info on until the entire page is complete, and finally the browser may not display it. So not recommended. (Not used)

2) Doing status update to a local file (or database) and then query through AJAX. This has been suggested in comments already, and you don't need to do just through uploading files. You'd use an AJAX call to kick start the process (using a common identifier such as a session to link all the calls), the process then updates its status to a file (linked to the common identifier) and then AJAX periodically calls the server and reads the status file. When the status file says "done" you can either redirect to a new page (generated using the status) or just update through AJAX. This method works very well - I last used it on mobile to keep a mobile site connected while waiting for background events; I have a "time-out" if all else failed.

3) Running the PHP script in batches. You need this if PHP has a max-execution-time and you're likely to exceed it. Basically you run for 30 seconds and then deliever a page with current status and a meta-refresh in the header that kick starts the next process from where the last one left of. You pass the status though the URL and the HTML. If you go this method, if the browser never hears back from the server then it can fail if internet connection is dodgy; so combining with the AJAX method (i.e. AJAX calling "please do first 50, wait for complete, update status, please do next 50 wait, update status etc) is a good hybrid solution. You also need to ensure that your script can safely handle the processing if you kick start from a previously processed position.

4) You open a javascript socket from browser to server, and update  through the sockets. I've never used this due to loack of support for sockets in browsers, but there are examples available if you know the audience and they have browsers that support sockets nicely.